# jQuery Validate Unobtrusive is not working for TextArea

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, jquery-validate, textarea

I'm using "jQuery Validate Unobtrusive" with ASP.NET MVC3 Razor.

I have a page with a "Comments" form, like this:

**Model**

```
public class CommentModel
{

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Url)]
    [Display(Name = "Website URL")]
    public string WebsiteUrl { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Message { get; set; }

}
```

**View**

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddComment", "Blog", new { @articleID = article.ID }))
    {
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.commentModel.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.commentModel.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.commentModel.Name)
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.commentModel.Email)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.commentModel.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.commentModel.Email)
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.commentModel.WebsiteUrl)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.commentModel.WebsiteUrl)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.commentModel.WebsiteUrl)
        </p>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.commentModel.Message)
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.commentModel.Message)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.commentModel.Message)
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" />
        </p>
    }
```

However, when the form is submitted, only `Name` and `Email` return a validation error, when `Message` should be too:

[image]

If I change `Message` from `TextAreaFor` to `TextBoxFor`, then the validation works correctly.

Why is this, and how can I get the validation to work on my text box?

---

It might also be worth noting I've not had to write any specific jQuery for this form. I followed a tutorial which explained this isn't required as its all handled by MVC3.

Comment: Can you include your Controller code?

Also, did you include both jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive in your layout or view?

Comment: @ron.defreitas Which controller method? Surely the `HttpPost` method wouldn't be relevant because this isn't reached because the client-side validation is preventing it? I've checked my Layout file, I've included: `jquery-1.5.1.min.js`, `jquery.validate.min.js` & `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`.

Comment: Can you view the rendered source of your form and make sure that the data-validation attribute has been added to the text area like the rest of the fields? Have you tried stepping through the POST of your form to see if the backend thinks there is input in the box?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Decorate the corresponding model property with `[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]` data annotation and use `Html.EditorFor` Helper method.

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Message { get; set; }
```

Now use  `@Html.EditorFor` Helper method

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.RoleDescription)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug with TextAreaFor when the model is nested. Put the contents of your CommentModel in the "root" model so to speak and everything works great. Or, change TextAreaFor to TextBoxFor and it works great!

On an unrelated topic, I feel validated that I am not the only one to try and nest my comment model like you are. This should really be fixed!

**Edit:**
Here is the bug ticket for the issue:

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/8576

**Edit2:**
Shyju's workaround of using EditorFor works! Interestingly, it also adds some additional class names to the output of the , so be careful they don't conflict with your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Shyju seems to work perfectly, but I had to add something additional to the Site.css file to make it work:

Apply @Shyju solution and Add the **css for textarea** :

```
textarea.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #e80c4d;
}
```

Now it works perfectly.